css assets not loading in spring boot application running on vscode
I am currently running a simple spring boot project via vscode. Everything works well but my css and javascript assets won't load when i run it.
this is my current project structure

and this is how I add the css for instance to the project:
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mycss.css}"


They are under /assets/css not /css.

for some reason that simply doesn't load all the assets. But when done with intellij it works perfectly well!

this worked for me
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/mycss.css}"/>


To use relative path in html you should use:
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{.assets/css/mycss.css}"
